# Mockito failing to mock Interface class in SpringBoot

Tags: java, spring-boot, junit, mockito

I am trying to test one test case using controller class with `service` interface and `interface` impl class. But it's  always failing and returning either `null` pointer exception or not found custom `exception` even mocking the method to return mock values.

## Controller.class

```
@RestController
    public class RestAPIController {

        @Autowired
        RestAPIService restAPIService;

        @PostMapping(path = "list/{id}")
        public ResponseEntity<List<Employee>> findByID(@PathVariable(value = "id") String id)
                throws RestAPIException {


            List<Employee> list = restAPIService.findByID(id);

            if (list == null || list.isEmpty()) {

               throw new IDNotFoundException(id);
            }

            return new ResponseEntity<>(list, HttpStatus.OK);
        }
```

## Service Interface:

```
@Service
public interface RestAPIService {

    public List<Employee> findByID(@Param("id") String id) throws RestAPIException;
}
```

## Service impl class:

```
@Service
public class RestAPIServiceImpl implements RestAPIService {


    @Override
    public List<Employee> findByID(String id) throws RestAPIException {

        return serviceUtils.transformationObj(repository.findByID(id));
    }
}
```

## Test Class

```
@Mock
RestAPIService restAPIServiceImpl;


@InjectMocks
RestAPIController restAPIController;

@Test
    public void testListByIDController() throws RestAPIException {

        Mockito.when(restAPIServiceImpl.findByID("1")).thenReturn(baseDTOData());

        ResponseEntity<List<Employee>> expectedList = restAPIController.findByID("1");

        assertEquals(1, expectedList.getBody().size());

    }

private List<Employee> baseDTOData() {
        List<Employee> list = new ArrayList<>();

        Employee e = new Employee();

        e.setId("2");

        list.add(e);

        return list;
    }
```

## pom.xml (using JUnit5)

```
<dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
            <!-- exclude junit 4 -->

            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>junit</groupId>
                    <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Junit 5 -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.junit.jupiter</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit-jupiter-api</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.junit.jupiter</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit-jupiter-engine</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.junit.platform</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit-platform-launcher</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Mockito extention -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.mockito</groupId>
            <artifactId>mockito-junit-jupiter</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
```

The above code is failing and enters into IDNotFoundException but mock return is not working.

Can anyone please help on this.

Comment: Remove `@Spy` for the controller.

Comment: after removing `@Spy` also getting the same as not returning the mock values and throwing id not found exception. thanks @M. Deinum

Comment: baseDTOData() is probably returning null or an empty list then. Post a **complete** minimal example reproducing the problem.

Comment: no, baseDTOData() having list with values. even in test case last 2 lines are not executing when run test. thanks @JB Nizet

Comment: If it returns `null`. Either the code you are showing isn't the code you are actually using, or you must be doing really weird things. The default behavior of a mock is to return an empty list if hte predicate doesn't match. Can you add the actual test case (instead of only the method).

Comment: You're contradicting yourself. First you say that the code "enters into IDNotFoundException". Then you say that the line `restAPIController.findByID("1");` is not executing. How could it throw an exception if it's not executing? Again, post a complete minimal example reproducing the issue.

Comment: added full code ..please help on this. thanks @JB Nizet,@M. Deinum

Comment: No, you didn't. Post a complete mnimal example. We must be able to copy and paste the code in our IDE, and run it without doing any modification.

Comment: Can you try:

`Mockito.when(restAPIServiceImpl.findByID(anyString())).thenReturn(baseDTOData());`

to see if it can mock when you said any id , not your specific "1". Maybe there is actually no id "1".

Comment: not working for `Mockito.anyString()` also. thanks @amer

Comment: Try to add
`@Before
  public void setUp() {
    MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this);
  }`
after @InjecMocks

Comment: even same result no change as getting idnotfoundexception only. thanks @amer